# Empty array at any search using FOSElasticaBundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have a problema that I cannot sort it out, I have tried everyhing I have found on the web for this.

So, I am fairly new in Symphony, I did not have any problems so far until I needed to implement a search engine. I have looked and found out that Elastico was a very good choice and I decided to implement it.

I have installed it using composer, no problems. For the very most basic of search, my config looks like this :

```
fos_elastica:
 clients: 
    default: { host: localhost, port: 80 }
 indexes:
    search:
        client: default
        types:
            story:
                mappings:
                    name: ~
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Website\WebBundle\Entity\Story
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~
```

I do not have any problems generating the data with `php app/console fos:elastica:populate`. The result are corectly inserted ( matching number or entries with the database entries ).

So, my problem is cannot display ANY results. I always have empty array as result for :

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.search.story');
$results = $finder->find('name');
```

Also empty result for :

`$repositoryManager = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.manager');
$repository = $repositoryManager->getRepository('WebsiteWebBundle:Story');
$results = $repository->find('name');`

And I have a record in the database with the name 'name' so I should get results. Searching for a letter doesn't work also.

So, can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong ? Or is there any way of displaying all the results so I can see that the results are there and only the searching fails ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You miss your mapping config.

You have to specify the attributes of the Class story to be indexed
ie:

```
mappings:
      id:
       type: integer
```